# Создание нового окна WinAPI

Tags: winapi, окно

Здравствуйте! Интересует такой вопрос, можно ли создавать N дополнительных отдельных окон в одном файле, т.е. у меня есть класс для окна Server со своим WndProc и класс для окна Client,если я буду создавать N отдельных окон класса Client,для каждого потребуется своя функция WndProc? 
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно. Несколько окон могут работать с одной оконной процедурой.

Другое дело, что написание GUI врукопашную с WinAPI было актуально 20 лет назад. Пора менять технологии на что-то типа Qt.

Comment: Т.е. сейчас уже не стоит разбираться как устроена работа на "низких" уровнях?

Comment: Сейчас актуальны кроссплатформенные фреймворки. Для десктопа это Qt

Comment: Никита Алексеев, если Вы точно знаете, что GUI Вам нужен ТОЛЬКО под Windows, то winapi - как раз для этого и подходит.